# Ionic how to loop and calculate the value from *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I get a series of data from an API that I created using Django Framework, and I loop it into my ionic using *ngFor

Here is the example of code:

```
      <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-4>
            {{user.fields.date}}
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-4>
                {{user.fields.duration}}
          </ion-col>
```

I would like to know is that any idea for me to calculate the sum of {{user.fields.duration}} in ts file or in the html ???

I am new to ionic , and I have no idea how to do it. Please help me, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to do that.

```
sumOf(field: string, array: number[]) {
  return array.reduce((p, n) => {
    p[field] += n[field];
    return p;
  }, 0);
}
```

In your HTML :

```
{{ sumOf('duration', user.fields) }}
```

The function will start with a value of zero, then will iterate over all of the items of your array (given the field), add it to the original number, then return it.

Comment: what should I pass into the field ?? and the array: number[] means ?? I have no idea how to do it...Can u explain in details please ?

Comment: I get array.reduce is not a function ?? Can you help me solve it please..

Comment: I won't explain to you how data binding and Javascript work. If you don't know what reduce do, don't know how to use data binding, and how to call a simple function, then you should work on that first.

Comment: But if reduce isn't a function, then you should use a polyfill.

Comment: of course I know how to call a function and what data binding is.. but this is completely new to me and I have no idea how it works..can you please explain in details for me please ?? This will save my life..please..

Comment: I explained how it works at the end of my answer. I won't explain what reduce does in details, you have documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create angular Pipe for sum:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sum'
})
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], attr: string): any {
        return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
    }
}
```

And call it like that:

```
<span>{{ user.fields| sum:'duration' }}</span>
```

Comment: Okay, but what is the items:any[], return items.reduce((a,b) ? what is that all about ??

Comment: To know more about reduce function. you can read this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9

Comment: when i click it shows the site cannot be reached ??